How to make the collison function iterop with the animation function in a 2-d platformer game
I am making a game using pygame.
But the collision using pygame.sprite.collidemask() and my animator() function don't seem to work together to show the expected output.
The gravity func of the player is:
    def apply_gravity(self, fps: int, gravity_acc: float) -> None:
            """
            This applies gravity to the player.
    
            @param: fps : int
                The max fps cap of the game.
            @param: gravity_acc : float
                The acceleration due to gravity of the game.
            """
            if not self.on_ground:
                # ? Using the formula v = u + (a * t)
                self.y_vel += self.time_in_air * gravity_acc
                self.time_in_air += fps / self.MILLISECONDS_IN_SECOND
            elif self.on_ground:
                self.jump_count = 0
                self.time_in_air = 0
                self.y_vel = 0

The Player animation function is:
def animator(self) -> None:
        action = "Idle"
        if self.y_vel < 0:
            if self.jump_count == 1:
                action = "Jump"
            elif self.jump_count == 2:
                action = "DoubleJump"
        elif self.y_vel > 0:
            action = "Fall"
        elif self.x_vel != 0:
            action = "Run"
        sprite = self.sprites[f"{action}_{self.direction}"]
        i = (self.animation_count // self.ANIMATION_DELAY) % len(sprite)
        self.image = sprite[i]
        self.mask = mask.from_surface(self.image)
        self.animation_count = 0

I have a terrain class that represents 1 terrain block.
The ScriptInit initializes the rect, image, mask of the object.
class Terrain(ScriptInit):
    def __init__(
        self,
        terrain_pos: tuple[int, int],
        terrain_image: Surface,
    ) -> None:
        tag = "None"
        super().__init__(terrain_pos, terrain_image, tag)

To check for collisions I use:
pygame.sprite.collidemask(terrain_obj, player)

When the player falls it clips in the terrain block. I fixed it by setting the player.bottom = terrain.top + 1 and setting player.onground = True. But now we have to check for falling, so I added:
 for terrain_obj in terrain_grp:
     if pygame.sprite.collidemask(player, terrain_obj):
         player.onground = True
         break
 else:
     player.onground = False

But then when we start to move: The action var starts to alternate b/w fall and run, i.e., the collision detection stopped working.
Any suggestions to how shall I proceed.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Since you haven't given all the code, it is hard to tell what your problem exactly is. Nevertheless, I think I have a plausible explanation. However, I can't test it, nor any of the proposed fixes.
Every time when the player collides with the ground, you give him the run/idle status and place him one pixel above the ground. As a result, the next time when you check whether the player is on the ground, he doesn't collide with the ground anymore. This makes that the player gets the fall status and falls into the platform. During the next check, the player is considered to be on the ground again as he collides with the platform. Then he gets the run/idle status and is placed above the platform again, resulting in the whole cycle to repeat.
This all results in an alternation between the fall and run/idle status.
An easy solution to this problem would be to place the player slightly overlapping with the platform, on terrain.top or even terrain.top - 1 if necessary. If this works with your mask logic, you can add a transparent or almost transparent row of pixels below the player, minimalising the visual impact of the solution.
Another solution could be to move the player temporarily one pixel downwards during collision detection. This would result in the player being in the platform during the collision detection. However, do not forget to reset the player's position appropriately after collision detection.
